# iphone app loader Icon dimension 50x50 72x72 error

Tags: iphone, icons, dimensions

I got all my six icons like said in itunes connect

my plist has list of 6 icons..

but still getting app loader error: please see picture.. what am I doing wrong? picture not working :(

Comment: in order for us to help, we need more information. please post your plist contents, as well as your directory structure/file names.

Comment: You should probably contact Apple with App Store questions rather than asking here.

Answer (score 0):

iphone app icons are:

57 * 57 iphone
114 * 114 iphone retina display

not sure where you've got 50 and 72 from

Comment: ok my mistake but I have all good dimensions, just found out I need to edit this page> targets > summary and use icon by yourself.. but thank you Thomas anyway, btw, which certificate I should use? for appstore when app loader ask me? developer or distribution?

Comment: distribution :) you should get a proper distribution certificate though, not an adhoc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Select the image in project navigator and in the Utilities pane tick on the radio button(in front of your App name) in Target Membership.